# How to create onclick event handler on every polygon with differeng key?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have many polygon in array.

I want to create onclick event handler.

Every click should have a different key for every single polygon so i can recognize which polygon were clicked.

I draw polygon using ForEach function in Java Script.

I was done with creating event handler but is not recognize which polygon clicked.

This is my code:

```
polygons.forEach(myfunction);

// Draw Polygon
function myfunction(item, index) {
    var polygon = L.polygon(item, { color: 'green' }).addTo(map);
    polygon.on('click', onPolygonClick);
}
function onPolygonClick() {
    Callback2.PerformCallback();
}
```

I want performing callback with the parameter is index of polygon clicked.

Any help for me?

Comment: you can use event.target.id

Comment: thank you for suggestion. but i dont know that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `index` variable of the `foreach` loop?

```
polygons.forEach(myfunction);

// Draw Polygon
function myfunction(item, index) {
    var polygon = L.polygon(item, { color: 'green' }).addTo(map);
    polygon.on('click', function() {
        onPolygonClick(index)); //pass the polygon's index to event handler
    }
}
function onPolygonClick(index) {
    //do something with the index
    console.log(index);
    Callback2.PerformCallback();
}
```

Comment: Great.. thank for give this code
```
polygon.on('click', function() {
        onPolygonClick(index)); //pass the polygon's index to event handler
    }
```
i new in javascipt so i don't know the ways for calling function.